# Securely restrict access to a private Debian repository

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, apt

I was looking for a method to restrict access to a private Debian repository and be able to authenticate to it non-interactively (i.e. using a script)

The most useful article I found if actually one from [Debian administration site](http://www.debian-administration.org/article/Restrict_Access_To_Your_Private_Debian_Repository) but the secure method uses ssh and public/private keys. It works great but each host's public key needs to be inside the remote authorized_keys file to successfully authenticate. 
It doesn't says nothing about providing password to ssh:// but I suppose it should be possible.

Have you tried other alternatives (e.g. ftps)?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The problem I have with the article above is that it doesn't only give APT repository access - it gives shell access to my APT repository machine. That's unacceptable risk.

Answer (score 5):

If you always run `apt-get` on your servers by hand (no automatic `apt-get` commands launched by crons), then you might consider using **ssh agent forwarding**.  This avoids having to manage one public/private keypair per server you manage, and it's probably safer than leaving private keys on every server.

**Initial configuration**
- connect to the servers you want to manage, and add something like this to `/etc/apt/sources.list` (this example assumes you want your servers to connect to the `manager` account):

```
    deb ssh://manager@my.repository.org/path other stuff
```

- create a pair of private/public keys on your own computer, with your login `johndoe` for example (provided your computer runs on debian: if not, you can do this from a debian server dedicated to management):

  ```
  ssh-keygen
  ```
- make sure it is protected by a strong keyphrase
- copy your public key to the repository server in `/home/manager/.ssh/authorized_keys`:

  ```
  ssh-copy-id manager@my.repository.org
  ```

**Once per management session**

- start the ssh agent on your machine by typing:

  ```
  eval `ssh-agent`
  ```
- add your key to the agent (this will require your passphrase):

  ```
  ssh-add
  ```

**Managing a server**

- connect to the server you want to manage using `ssh -A` (`-A` activates agent forwarding):

  ```
  ssh -A some.server.org
  ```
- switch to root (if you want to use `sudo` you need to configure `/etc/sudoers` or else `sudo` will break agent forwarding, [read this](https://serverfault.com/questions/107187/sudo-su-username-while-keeping-ssh-key-forwarding)):

  ```
  su
  ```
- you should now be able to connect to the repository's manager account using ssh without typing your password again, thanks to agent forwarding.  Therefore, `apt-get` should work just fine:

  ```
  apt-get udate
  ```

**Ending your management session**

- Once you have finished managing your servers, remove your keys from the agent:

  ```
  ssh-add -D
  ```

**Advantages**

- Not much initial configuration is required
- Just one private key is required
- Private key is protected by a strong passphrase
- If someone gains root access to one of your server, they will not have immediate access to your repository server.

  - Note that if the hacker is patient and qualified, he can wait until you connect to the server using agent-forwarding, and he can hijack the forwarding mechanism in order to gain access to your repository server.
  - To help prevent that, you can use `ssh-ask` in order to accept/refuse every attempt to use your key.
  - In any case, the hacker will *not* gain access to the private key itself: he will just be able to hijack the forwarding mechanism in order to *use* the key, and only during the time you are connected to the server.

Comment: Thanks again MiniQuark. Actually, the updates are unattended, but this is a great method that I could apply for testing purposes.

Comment: My pleasure! :)  Glad if it helps.

Answer (score 4):

One way to do this is just to allow a certain set of IPs to access the repository. This works very well for LAN and VPN.

Simple and efficient.

Comment: Thanks Antoine :). Actually, the repository that I have now is accessible using that method (http over a OpenVPN connection). I restrict the IPs that belong to the VPN. The drawback here is that every host needs to be connected to the VPN to access the repo, with is a little annoying (manage several certificates/keys). Sorry for not specifying that in the question.

Comment: True, it's bothersome to manage OpenVPN but it makes managing the security to your repository very simple. Also, users don't have to bother with credentials once inside the VPN.

Answer (score 2):

The ssh + public/private keys solution is not *that* bad:

- login as root on the client machine
- type `ssh-keygen`, then `ssh-copy-id your_login@your.repository.org`
- edit `/etc/apt/sources.list` and add something like:

  ```
  deb ssh://your_login@your.repository.org/path other stuff
  ```

Granted, it requires you to put each server's public key in the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file on the server, but it's not that complicated (see above) and it gives you control over which servers you allow or not at any given time (you can remove a key at any time in `authorized_keys`).

Comment: Thanks MiniQuark. Yes, this solution isn't that bad, but ssh-copy-id doesn't work if password authentication is disabled in openssh server. I thought on spreading the same key file on each client using the repository to be able to use it. For more security, the a user with minimal permissions would be used. It's almost the same as sharing credentials. I'm currently testing this method to check how behaves/work.

Answer (score 2):

You could setup an https access to your repository, secured by login/password (basic authentication).  The problem is that you need to put the cleartext login/password in `/etc/apt/sources.list` (note: [there is a patch](http://www.mail-archive.com/debian-bugs-closed@lists.debian.org/msg258136.html) to allow the login/password to be put in `/root/.netrc` instead).

Comment: This is probably the best solution, also it's not netrc but /etc/apt/auth.conf. Docs here: https://manpages.debian.org/testing/apt/apt_auth.conf.5.en.html

Answer (score 0):

The link in your question shows multiple methods. You want number 2, https + basic authentication.

Comment: Thanks Justin. I think that https transport with apt only works if apt-transport-https is installed. This is an interesting alternative. The only drawback is the credentials in sources.list

Comment: chmod 600 /etc/apt/sources.list