# Retain agent-forwarding in sudo

Tags: ssh, sudo, ssh-tunnel, scp, ssh-agent

I want to be able to connect to a server, start a sudo shell, then use agent forwarding to connect to another server (in order to use SCP to copy files to a protected area). But:

```
ubuntu@tunnelator:/var/www$ ssh -p 10022 stevebennett@localhost
Last login: Fri Apr  5 10:54:03 2013 from localhost
~ exit
Connection to localhost closed.

ubuntu@tunnelator:/var/www$ sudo ssh -p 10022 stevebennett@localhost
Password:
```

Presumably, starting the sudo shell is killing the agent forwarding. The difference is this:

```
debug1: Offering RSA public key: id_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 277
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
```

versus:

```
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
```

Is there a way to make this work? (The setup is roughly as described here: http://codysoyland.com/2010/jun/6/ssh-tip-automatic-reverse-tunnels-workflow-simplif/)

Comment: Maybe this can help:

http://serverfault.com/questions/107187/sudo-su-username-while-keeping-ssh-key-forwarding

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to user157963's suggestion, this turns out to be easy:

```
sudo -E ssh -p 10022 stevebennett@localhost
```

Or, to be a bit more selective, you can do this:

```
sudo su -l -c "export SSH_AUTH_SOCK=$SSH_AUTH_SOCK; ssh -p 10022 stevebennett@localhost"
```

(Note this only works when su'ing to the root user - it needs to be able to read the original socket file.)

I had mistakenly thought that the $SSH_AUTH_SOCK environment variable was already being preserved. Tip: the following command doesn't tell you anything useful :)

```
sudo echo $SSH_AUTH_SOCK
```

Whereas this does:

```
sudo bash -c 'echo $SSH_AUTH_SOCK'
```

Comment: Additionally you can just `sudo -sE` if you want to have a shell as root. `-E` preserves the current environment which includes `$SSH_AUTH_SOCK` which houses the forwarding agent information