# Ansible, Vagrant, sudo and ssh-agent

Tags: ssh, sudo, ansible, github, ssh-agent

So I've seen [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/107187/ssh-agent-forwarding-and-sudo-to-another-user) and added the `Defaults env_keep+=SSH_AUTH_SOCK` into my `/etc/sudoers` file but I am still unable to clone from github on my Vagrant box using `sudo: true` and `sudo_user: <user>` in my ansible playbook. I'd like to clone the code as the user I created to run it but it is proving to be really frustrating. I can do `ssh git@github.com` when I log in via `vagrant ssh` but when I then do `sudo -u <user> ssh git@github.com` I get the Permission Denied error. When I echo the `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` value as the specific user I see that it is set:

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:/tmp$ sudo -u derp echo $SSH_AUTH_SOCK
/tmp/ssh-w3XYbqlMnX/agent.1592
```

Comment: did you also modify your `/etc/pam.d/sudo` file?

Comment: @Jakuje I did not. Do I also put the `env_keep` directive there or is there something else I need to do?

Comment: Sorry I understood the question wrong. Did you add the line on your host or on your Vagrant box?

Comment: @Jakuje Vagrant box.

Answer (score 3):

I think the issue is the /tmp file doesn't have permissions. If you

```
 sudo -u root ssh git@github.com
```

That might work since root can read the files

To fix this as the vagrant user run

```
setfacl -m otheruser:x   $(dirname "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK")
setfacl -m otheruser:rwx "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK"
```

That should give the `otheruser` rights to get into the directory and read the file.